# Reference request for Godement's "Topologie algébrique et théorie des faisceaux"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

Does anybody know if an *english translation* of this paper exists please?

Comment: Entiendo este tipo de preguntas, pero qué poco me gustan.

Comment: Não é um artigo!

Comment: there is a Russian translation (Algebraicheskaya topologiya i teoriya puchkov), but no otther language it seems.

Answer (score 7):

Probably it does not exist. I checked Zentralblatt; it usually reviews all translations. It has the Russian translation mentioned in the comments, but no English one.

(In general, translations from French to English are rare in mathematics, probably because the demand is negligible: the languages share 60% of all vocabulary (I mean roots), and in Mathematics even more).

Answer (score 1):

Even though there probably doesn't exist a *translation*. I think section 2.1 and chapter 7 of *Complex analytic and differential geometry* by Jean-Pierre Demailly basically follow narrative (with modification on some notations) of Godement and cover most of material of Godement's. So maybe Demailly's book is a good replacement.